# Repeater inside a ListView: how to bind a command and call it ?

Tags: asp.net, listview

Scenario: I've a Repeater inside a ListView. 
Inside the repeater i've a LinkButton; This is the syntax

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkRemoveComment" Text="Delete" Visible='<%# CheckVisibility() %>' CommandName="DeleteComment" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")%>'> </asp:LinkButton>
```

I don't know the syntax, in server side code, to call:

- DeleteComment
- CheckVisibility

I don't know because repeater is nested in an ListView. 
And inserting code inside ListView ItemCommand not works!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example :

```
.aspx
------------------ 
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Command" CommandName="MyUpdate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("erid") %>'>LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>


.cs
------------------
protected void LinkButton1_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "MyUpdate"){
        //e.CommandArgument --> contain the erid value
        //Do something
    }
}
```